# Array in For loop?

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop

Lets take for example this code:
I wanted to use string "name" as a name of the array that i am using in for loop but instead I receive string "array". How to use this string for a name of my array?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  int array[3];
  array[0] = 1;
  array[1] = 2;
  array[2] = 3;
  string name = "array";
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    cout << name[i] << endl;
  }
}
```

Comment: This code won't even come close to compiling, get back to us after you've tried a little harder.

Comment: C++ doesn't have reflection - there is no general way to refer to a variable (or anything else) using a string containing its identifier.

Comment: If you are trying to relate a value to a key instead then you can use a map. Otherwise what you want is not possible here.

Comment: @MattPhillips Better?

Comment: @Angew Nope. That is instead going to grab a char out of the string.

Comment: @Aleks I was referring to Matt's comment on "this code won't compile." Seeing as this is a collaborative site and the OP's first question, I just fixed the obvious oversights in the code to make it compile.

Comment: I suppose a good answer would be implementation of that code using a map, and some STL container for `array` instead of plain C array.

Comment: @Angew Sorry I just noticed the name difference.

Comment: @Agnew Yes, the required edits were indeed simpler than I first realized.  In any case your first comment has answered the question. :)

Comment: Start by asking yourself *why* you need to do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Expanding my comment into an answer.

C++ doesn't have reflection: there is no general way to refer to a variable (or anything else) using a string containing its identifier.

There are, however, data structures available for retrieving data based on a key, such as a string. In your case, you could do something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main() {
  std::map<std::string, std::vector<int> > allArrays;  // mapping strings to vectors of ints
  allArrays["array"].push_back(1);  // fill vector stored under key "array"
  allArrays["array"].push_back(2);
  allArrays["array"].push_back(3);

  // another way:
  std::vector<int> &vec = allArrays["another_array"];
  vec.push_back(-1);
  vec.push_back(-2);
  vec.push_back(-3);

  std::string name = "array";

  for (size_t i = 0; i < allArrays[name].size(); ++i) {
    std::cout << allArrays[name][i] << '\n';  //not using endl - no need to flush after every line
  }
}
```

Comment: Why don't we need to flush after the line?

Comment: @David The question stands the other way round: why would we need to? If we don't, we shouldn't be doing extra work which can slow down the run rather significantly. I'm just trying to correct the misconception that `<< endl` is the default way to put a newline in a `std::ostream`. It's not; it means "put a newline and flush the stream." This sample program will get flushed when `main()` ends. In larger programs, it might be better to do the flush after the entire output - it could certainly be significantly faster.